# How to aggregate the expanded values - python - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have input like this:

```
     column1     column2
    MGI:97874   MP:0008796
    MGI:97874   MP:0009395
    MGI:97874   MP:0009937
    MGI:97874   MP:0011098
    MGI:97874   MP:0011703
    MGI:96522   MP:0001614
    MGI:96522   MP:0000364
    MGI:96522   MP:0006093
```

My question is how to combine the rows of the same value (in the column one) in one line, so the output will be like that:

```
MGI:97874 MP:0008796 MP:0009395 MP:0009937 MP:0011098 MP:0011703
MGI:96522 MP:0001614 MP:0000364 MP:0006093
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
g = df.groupby('column1')['column2'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    column1                                                       column2
0  MGI:96522                          [MP:0001614, MP:0000364, MP:0006093]
1  MGI:97874  [MP:0008796, MP:0009395, MP:0009937, MP:0011098, MP:0011703]
```

Now that you have aggregated dataframe, you can print in whatever format you want.

May be soemthing like:

```
for idx, x in g.iterrows():
    print(x['column1'], [y for y in x['column2']])
```

Output:

```
MGI:96522 ['MP:0001614', 'MP:0000364', 'MP:0006093']
MGI:97874 ['MP:0008796', 'MP:0009395', 'MP:0009937', 'MP:0011098', 'MP:0011703']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a dict like this:

```
df.groupby('column1')['column2'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).to_dict()
```